# How to pass randomly generated test data from one test step to other test step

Tags: java, selenium

We have an automation framework which uses excel sheet as test data.
To reduce test data file creation efforts i have used Java fake library to generate random data.My problem is,I have to pass these randomly generated test data to other test steps which compare these data with database.
Test Data files are having following fields:
1.First name 
2.Last name
3.Address
4. orderid..etc
And these data is generated randomly and entering in website .

I tried to store all random data in text files.But i just want to avoid reading .txt file go through each line and the compare values  with database.
Text File looks like-
Test case-1|Name-1|address-1|order Id-1
Test Case-2|Name-2|address-2|order-id-2
etc..

Is there any other way to store these values and compare with database?

Comment: Are the other test steps part of your selenium test? Then just store each record of test data in a new object with a class having fields for first name, last name, address (just like the database)?

Comment: yes other steps is also part of selenium.These test might run for 5k +records will storing in object cause any  performance issue?

Comment: 5k records should fit into memory. Idealy a single test will only store a single record, which could be garbage collected afterwards, but even a list of 5k records is ok. I would rather expect that running a selenium test with 5k different records would be a performance issue - independently of the place where the records are stored.

Comment: You can create public Class called let's say 'user'. This class has all necessary strings (or other types) incliding setters and getters. Your test class extends user class so you can create and access user data in your test f.e.: String firstName = user1.getFirstName()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just create an bean as:

```
public class TestData {

public static String FirstName;
public static String lastName;
public static String Address;
public static String orderid;
public static String getFirstName() {
    return FirstName;
}
public static void setFirstName(String firstName) {
    FirstName = firstName;
}
public static String getLastName() {
    return lastName;
}
public static void setLastName(String lastName) {
    TestData.lastName = lastName;
}
public static String getAddress() {
    return Address;
}
public static void setAddress(String address) {
    Address = address;
}
public static String getOrderid() {
    return orderid;
}
public static void setOrderid(String orderid) {
    TestData.orderid = orderid;
}
```

}

You can use direct variable as I have put them public or getter/setter.
As the variable is static you call them directory with className

***Example:***

**StepDefination1Class**

```
TestData.setFirstName("Shubham");
```

OR

```
TestData.FirstName="Shubham";
```

Use the same varible in another class as below:

**StepDefination2Class**

```
String Fname = TestData.getLastName();
```

OR

```
String Fname =TestData.FirstName;
```